# save table rows count in local storage

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, google-chrome-extension, local-storage

Hello I am currently using a script that takes your table data and saves it in local storage where I call it in another js file.

I have a script that succesfully can save the table data exactly how I would like, But I have been struggling on how to implement a count for how many table rows there are in the table before the data is saved in local storage.

Here is what I have tried:

```
$(function() {

  loadAllTasks();

  $("#addTask").click(function() {
    let cells = Array.prototype.map.call($("#items-table")[0].rows, row => {
      return Array.prototype.map.call(row.cells, cell => cell.innerHTML);
    });
    var task = {
      cells: cells
    };
    task.Name = $("#taskName").val();
    var itemCount = $("#items-table tr").length - 1;

    var count = {
      itemCount: itemCount
    };
    saveTaskInStorage(task);
    saveCountInStorage(count);

  });

  function saveTaskInStorage(task) {
    var savedTasks = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('tasks'));
    if (!savedTasks || typeof(savedTasks) !== "object")
      savedTasks = {};
    savedTasks[task.Name] = task;
    localStorage.setItem('tasks', JSON.stringify(savedTasks));

    alert("Task has been Added");
  }
  function saveCountInStorage(count) {
    var savedCount = localStorage.getItem('counts')
    savedCount = {};
    savedCount[task.Name] = count;
    localStorage.setItem('counts', savedCount);
  }

  function loadCountFromStorage1(taskName) {
   var savedCount = localStorage.getItem('counts');
    return savedCount[taskName];
  }

  function loadAllTasks() {
    var savedTasks = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('tasks'));
    if (!savedTasks || typeof(savedTasks) !== "object")
      return;
    for (var taskName in savedTasks) {
      $("#loadTask").append('<option>' + taskName + '</option>')
    }
  }

});

function loadTaskFromStorage1(taskName) {
   var savedTasks = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('tasks'));
    return savedTasks[taskName];
}
```

then in the other js file I call these functions:

```
function loadAllTasks() {

    // Get all saved tasks from storage and parse json string to javascript object
    var savedTasks = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('tasks'));

    // To be sure that object exists on localStorage
    if (!savedTasks || typeof (savedTasks) !== "object")
        return;

    // Get all property name of savedTasks object (here it means task names)
    for (var taskName in savedTasks){
        $("#select-task").append('<option>' + taskName + '</option>')
    }
}
function loadTaskFromStorage(taskName) {
    var savedTasks = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('tasks'));

    // Return the task by its name (property name on savedTasks object)
    return savedTasks[taskName];
}

function loadCountFromStorage(taskName) {
   var savedCount = localStorage.getItem('counts');
    return savedCount[taskName];
}

loadAllTasks();

var task = loadTaskFromStorage($("#select-task").val());
```

then I just do:

```
alert(task.cells);
```

this works perfectly, it alerts all the custom saved data in the table that I saved.

I then have tried a bunch of different options for this:

```
alert(task.itemCount);
```

and a bunch of variations of that.

I want to be able to do:

```
alert(task.count);
```

this then will alert me the number of rows in the table of the saved task I currently have selected in my select html.

I also tried getting rid of the saveCount functions and just modifing this:

```
var task = {
  cells: cells,
  count: count
};
```

but unfortunately this also does not work.

I would really appreciate it if anyone could help me on how I would save the table row count in local storage and be able to call it on each different saved task in the select on my html/ js file.

each saved task will have a different count so I want to do task.count

Thanks for the Help <3!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should really look into using a front end framework like [React](https://reactjs.org/) or [Angular](https://angular.io/). You are looping through dom elements and saving its inner html as values in your task when what you really need is something data driven. However, I think this might solve your issue.

In your click handler for `#addTask` you have

```
let cells = Array.prototype.map.call($("#items-table")[0].rows, row => {
  return Array.prototype.map.call(row.cells, cell => cell.innerHTML);
});
var task = {
  cells: cells
};
```

Try adding in a counter here

```
let count = 0;     
let cells = Array.prototype.map.call($("#items-table")[0].rows, row => {
  count += 1;
  return Array.prototype.map.call(row.cells, cell => cell.innerHTML);
});
var task = {
  cells: cells
  count: count
};
```

Hopefully that works for you